# How does Victor get away with saying "Two weeks..." to Gale in front of Gus?

Tags: breaking-bad

In S4E1 ("Boxcutter")and Gus asks when things will be up and running, Gale says, In a month and Victor says, Two weeks. Gale then reluctantly agrees. Gus says nothing.

This seems like fairly impertinent of Victor (about whom we know almost nothing but he looks like he is in his early 20s if not late teens.

> Is this something, along with later behavior which led to Victor's murder?

Or did Gus actually not mind Victor saying this particular thing, which sort of reminds me of what Nodoze said to Walt in front of Tuco?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Victor's statement was not made as Gale's assistant, but rather as Gus' informant on Gale's progress.

Gale is taking more time than is strictly necessary because he is padding for safety and preparedness. Victor knows that it can be done quicker and informs Gus of this. Gus trusts and believes Victor. Gale knows this and therefore yields rather than try to argue with Victor in front of Gus, because he knows he will lose the debate.

Victor wasn't speaking out of turn. He was doing precisely what Gus wants him to do: observe and report on Gale.

Comment: this implies that his ultimate (spoiler) fate is due to him showing his face at Gale's apt. not because he attempted cooking -- do u agree?

Comment: @releseabe Yes. Gus is known for keeping an insanely high level of secrecy, and Victor's value as an experienced cook is not enough for Gus to keep him when Victor has also become a liability, even with all the animosity between Gus and Walt.

Comment: I think that might be further confirmed when Gus sees the (pretty accurate) sketch of Victor at the police/FBI office, as it shows Gus was not being overly paranoid in his assessment.

Answer (score 1):

Victor is holding a notebook and checking off progress.  To me it looks like his job is managing Gale. Not sure how old he was meant to be but his actor was around 30 at the time.