# When Gale says, a month and Victor says, in front of Fring, 2 weeks, was that the beginning of the end for Victor?

Tags: breaking-bad

This is major spoilers for season 4, episode 1.

The exchange in question occurs at the beginning of Boxcutter. Fring asks Gale when he thinks he will be ready to start production and when Gale says a month and Victor quietly contradicts him by asserting that it can happen in half that time, looking a Fring's face, I do not see a negative reaction.

It is extremely clear that Fring respects Gale's expertise and has funded him liberally. We have no reason to believe that Victor has any expertise and if in fact he did, why would Gale or Walt be needed?

That Fring does not react to Victor with no apparent basis contradicting a PHD chemist of course does not mean he did not hear Victor. One might have expected Fring to subtly express displeasure by simply saying, A month is fine, but when Gale then seems to agree that two weeks is an okay estimate, Fring leaves it at that.

But was Fring actually angry that Victor, who basically is just muscle for him -- perhaps that he could actually cook was even a surprise to Fring -- spoke up at that moment?

Did it actually plant a seed that resulted in the horrific scene later in the episode?

A more simple question is, Why did Victor open his mouth and why did Fring say nothing since rushing his chemist could not be a very good idea?

Comment: Not sure about that, because iirc Victor was holding and reading the schedule, which suggests that he was in charge of supervising the project. Imo the goal of this mini-scene was maybe to have us enjoy a last and calm moment with a character that was just killed, and with another one who is soon going to be (violently).

Comment: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/117320/how-does-victor-get-away-with-saying-two-weeks-to-gale-in-front-of-gus?rq=1

Comment: @GendoIkari: I had zero memory i asked this already.

Comment: I didn’t notice it was the same author!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Victor get away with saying "Two weeks..." to Gale in front of Gus?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/117320/1006)